# Detect when an item is declared as record?

Tags: 2010, records-management

This is a weird scenario.

1. user needs to create a document library when a calendar event is created, and show in the calendar event a link to the document library.
   My solution: create a feature receiver that detected when items are added, detect if the new column is already created, if not create one. and then programatically create a document library, and update the column contents with the link to the new library.
2. user wants that after 30 days the entire document library is archived, can this be done?
   If this is possible, then the link on step 1 would be broken, any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "the entire document library be archived," do you mean the contents of the library be moved to another place pr the library is "moved" (deleted and recreated in another place)? Either way the result would be the same: a dead link... My only suggestion is a little obvious. In the code you write that moves the library or its contents (I'd likely use a one-time timer job), look up the originating calendar list item and change the link. If you are storing it in the versioned "comments" field then this make clicking the bad link a possibility, so I would consider having this as a URL field type rather than putting it in the versioned comments field.